# Unable to produce alert message via obtaining result from Flask view in Ajax

Tags: html, ajax, flask, alert

My HTML code snippet

```html
<button onclick="myfunc()">Try it</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myfunc(){
  setInterval("wowwah()",3000); // call every 3 seconds
  };
  function wowwah(){
  $.ajax({
  url:"/myStatus", //the Flask view containing python script
  type:"post",
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(result){ alert(result); 
  }
  });
  }
  </script>
```

My Flask App view

```js
@application.route('/myStatus', methods=['POST','GET'])
def check_status():
 global have_plot
 if not have_plot:
  return jsonify('Not Ready')
 else: return jsonify('Ready')
```

However there is no alert message popping up in my web browser. I want the alert message to pop up and display either 'Ready' or 'Not Ready' every 3 seconds of checking in with the Flask app

**What have I done wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are getting an HTTP error, that you are not seeing because your Ajax does not handle HTTP errors.

Try to change your Ajax to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/myStatus", //the Flask view containing python script
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){ alert(result); },
    error: function(result) { console.error(result); }
});
```

Then you'll be able to see a posible error in the Developer console.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I figured out the reason for my code not working. I have to use the 'GET' method for the result response to be captured by my AJAX.